# Source Control Workflow: synching code changes on a staging webserver

Tags: tfs

I am currently using TFS to source changes to a web site code base. Currently, when I'm done making a change, I need to deploy the changes to a web server for review by the end user.

Generally the way I would do this is just connect to that machine via RDP, open visual studio and get latest to pull changes...

However, this only works if I'm the only one working on the entire site. If someone else RDP in to make changes, the site is locked to my TFS account, and they can't make any changes to it...

They could pull their own copy of the site into their own machine via TFS and check in the changes there but because so much of their part is done on the database (vs code) they'd have to duplicate everything they do into the website every time them commit a change, so they prefer to work directly on the machine...

is there any way to make this work, a better way to set this up so I can pull their changes into my local copy via TFS?

my biggest problem to overcome is the fact that when I Get Latest on the webserver via RDP it locks the entire solution to my TFS account, so that when they login to RDP with their credentials, they can't make any changes because the files are checked in, and of course they can't checkout because of course the solution is tied to my account.

If I can get past that I think we'd be okay.

any info is appreciated, please let me know if I can provide more context, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you set up a different TFS workspace for each user on your RDP machine?  This should allow multiple users to use the TFS client to pull the same solution on the same machine without issue.

Comment: that's definitely possible, but how would I then sync their changes to the actual website? right now I'm pulling latest into the actual website folder, if they are working in another folder they'd be working on a copy of the site

Comment: I'd separate your individual workspaces from the production website files.  You can get latest (in your production website file folder) using the Windows Explorer add-on (enabled from the Microsoft Team Foundation Server Power Tools download -- Google for a version specific to your version of TFS).  You may also want to look in to continuous integration solutions like CruiseControlDotNet to handle deployments to staging and/or production environments, even though that's a little outside the scope of the question.